# Android, Best way to store lists of data

Tags: android

I'm stuck on how I should go about storing some user data in my application I'm building.

The data being stored is effectively a list of items, like a list of car objects.
The application must be able to store multiple lists.

Now i know there's several ways to store data, but I'm unsure what would be the best approach to storing these multiple lists.

so far i can only think of:

1) create table(s) for the lists.

2) storing each list as either a text file or xml file.

if anyone can explain what would be the best approach and if there are better alternatives what they would be.

Comment: I will say if you don't require synchronization, you should opt for XML files, relational databases have their own advantages though but managing XML files is much easier as i perceive.

Comment: XML's not bad but IMO more time consuming to code than JSON serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically a few options:

1. Use a SQlite Database and optionally hide it behind a ContentProvider
2. Let your Classes implement Serializable and save things with ObjectStream to some file to persist them
3. Implement some custom String serialization (eg. JSONObject / JSONArray / XML) to save your objects in SharedPreferences

Pros/Cons:

1. Quite an overhead but faster than the others when you got more than a couple of objects.
2. Easy to implement, not that fast, OK for a couple objects
3. Easy to implement, even slower, OK for a few objects, upgrading your data structure can break thinks. be prepared.

So in the end, it depends on your use case.

Further readings: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html